# Force Bootstrap form columns to wrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a simple Bootstrap form with two columns so when I resize Browser the text fields will keep their widths and columns will wrap. Here is my code:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
        <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
        <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
    </div>
</form>
```

And [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/quyB6/170/)

But instead, when I resize, inputs get smaller and no column wrapping occurs. What am I doing wrong?

Edit.
Added a picture:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are using `col-xs-6`, which means will always have 2 columns in the smallest breakpoint of Bootstrap (xs), because `col-*-6` means 50% `width`, therefore not wrapping.

To wrap in the smallest breakpoit, you need to use instead `col-xs-12 col-sm-6` or `col-xs-12 col-md-6`, which means it will be 100% `width` in `col-xs` and `50%` in `col-sm` and up or `col-md` or up,  depending on when you which break-point you want the columns to wrap.

As mentioned by @banzay in comments below, there is no need to use `col-xs-12` along with larger breakpoints, so I've updated the snippet below.

More info on Twitter Bootstrap grid options [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<form>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Line Height</label>
    <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="name" class="control-label">Padding Top</label>
    <input type="email" value='' class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Ime" />
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to work. Do you mind briefly explain why it works?

Comment: I see. Thanks again.

Comment: no need to define `col-xs-12` along with larger breakpoints, because it's defined by default. Pls, read BS docs carefully.

Comment: ya I'm aware of that, but to explain this specific situation I use it, to make it more understandable, I'll update the answer

Comment: Just added a picture from my application. While I get column wrapping but before it happens the text fields are overlapping. Any idea why? I am using exactly the same code.

Comment: doesn't happen in my snippet, so other CSS rules maybe

Comment: Interesting, if I use <div class="card" style="width:1000px"> providing a concrete width then I dont get the side effect.